# how to make the titles in pagerSlidingTabstrip dynamic?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I need to change the titles in the pager according to the items that are dynamically changing in the child fragments in the pager. I have tried it this way

```
     TextView title = (TextView) mPagerSlidingTabStrip.getChildAt(1);
        title.setText("Posts " + count);
```

But it doesnt seem to be working.
Thanks in advance

Comment: check your count value and type. if required add count.toString();

Comment: @Rakesh that was not the problem. count was of type String. RRR solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this to access textview of each tab

```
    LinearLayout mTabsLinearLayout = ((LinearLayout) mPagerSlidingTabStrip.getChildAt(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabsLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView) mTabsLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        tv.setText("title");
    }
```

Now you want perticular tab's textview so

```
LinearLayout mTabsLinearLayout = ((LinearLayout) mPagerSlidingTabStrip.getChildAt(0));
TextView tv = (TextView) mTabsLinearLayout.getChildAt(<perticular tab position>);
tv.setText(yourText);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following demo code is also helpful for changing tab title dynamically:

```
private LinearLayout mTabsLinearLayout;
public void setUpTabStrip(int position)
  {
    this.mTabsLinearLayout = ((LinearLayout)this.tabsStrip.getChildAt(0));
for (int i=0;i<mTabsLinearLayout.getChildCount();i++)
{
  TextView tempTextView = (TextView)this.mTabsLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
  if (i == position) {
    tempTextView.setText("Your Text");
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. You can also change according to your requirement.

```
public void setTabText(int tabPosition, String text) {
   LinearLayout mTabsLinearLayout = ((LinearLayout) mPagerSlidingTabStrip.getChildAt(0));
     for (int i = 0; i < mTabsLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) mTabsLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if(i == tabPosition) {
        tv.setText(text);
     }
   }
}
```